# Coloring elements in nested list consistently over all sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

Coloring elements of sublists has been dealt with in another question.

A solution for sublists was presented along the following lines.

```
Permutations[{1, 2, 3}] // 
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, #, {1, #} & /@ Range[2, 2]] & // 
MapAt[Style[#, Blue] &, #, {2, #} & /@ Range[3, 3]] &
```

This produces the output of a list of permutations {{1,2,3},{1,3,2}, {3,2,1}}, in which the first sublist {1,2,3} has the element 2 (in position 2) colored red and the second sublist {1,3,2} has the element 2 (in position 3) colored blue.

I would like to obtain the result where *all* sublists have the 
second element colored red and the third colored blue.

This should be produced regardless of the number of sublists in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the coloring function for each sublist using `/@`.

```
(MapAt[Style[#, Blue] &, MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, #, 2], 3] &) /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

Version 12 introduced [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) which is a convenient generalization of `MapAt`:

```
SubsetMap[Thread[Style[#, {Red, Blue}]]&, #, {2, 3}]& /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

An alternative to `SubsetMap` and `MapAt` is to modify parts directly:

```
list = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}];
list[[All, {2, 3}]] = Thread[Style[#, {Red, Blue}]] & /@ list[[All, {2, 3}]];
list
```

> same result

In versions 12.2+, we can also use [`ApplyTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html):

```
f = Map[Thread@Style[#, {Red, Blue}] &];

list = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}];
list[[All, {2, 3}]] //= f;
list
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Using `MapThread`:**

```
MapThread[Style[#1, #2] &, {#, {Black, Red, Blue}}] & /@ 
 Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `SequenceReplace`:

```
l = Permutations[Range[3]];
colors = {Black, Red, Blue};

Map[Style[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, SequenceReplace[l, {x_} :> Transpose@{x, colors}],{2}]
```

Or using `SequenceReplace` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
SequenceReplace[l, {x_} :> Transpose@{x, colors}] /. {x_, y_} :> Style[x, y]
```

[image]

**Edit**:

Thanks, @Syed, for your kindly suggestion:

```
Transpose[{#, colors}] & /@ l /. {a_, b_} :> Style[a, b]
```

Comment: Simpler: `Transpose[{#, colors}] & /@ l /. {a_, b_} :> Style[a, b]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}];

c = {Black, Red, Blue};
```

Using `ReplacePart`

```
ReplacePart[a, {i_, j_} :> Style[a[[i, j]], c[[j]]]]
```

[image]